# How to communicate data between controllers in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am in the painfully slow process of learning Ember and find the guides and documentation severely limited when it comes to non-trivial examples.

To my question now.

Given the following router definition:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
this.resource('home', function() {
  this.resource('weather', function() {
    this.route('site', {path: '/:weather_site'});
  });
});
```

When the user enters the home.weather.index route the model hook executes and fetches all weather information from the server. When the user then enters home.weather.some_site the model hook of the new route would bring weather data for that particular site from the server. How can this redundancy be prevented? In other words, how can controllers communicate data to each other? Should I use the setupController hook in each Route to achieve this or are there better ways?

Are there any good resources to help me understand the data flow in and out of Ember? Are there any good resources to help me learn Ember faster than digging into the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can this redundancy be prevented?

It's not clear if/how/why the model hook for home/weather/index would fetch all weather information from the server. If that's desired behavior, then totally agreed there is no reason to fetch the same data when user enters home/weather/site.

If you are using ember-data there should be no redundancy since:

- when user visits home/weather/index `App.Site.find()` fetches all weather data
- when they visit home/weather/site `App.Site.find(weather_site)` returns site from cache and does not make a new request to the server
- if user visits home/weather/site directly (or refreshes browser) then `App.Site.find(weather_site)` will call server and fetch just data for that site.

So unless there is something I'm missing there is no redundancy to prevent.

> In other words, how can controllers communicate data to each other?

Seems unnecessary, but since you ask: Controllers communicate with one another via bindings. You declare a dependency from one controller to another via the controller's `needs` property, then Ember inject's a that dependency automatically. See the ember guide [dependencies-between-controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) for more on how this works.

> Should I use the setupController hook in each Route to achieve this or are there better ways?

That shouldn't be necessary in this case.

> Are there any good resources to help me understand the data flow in and out of Ember?

Not clear what you mean by data flow. Best guess is that you'd learn a lot from Luke Melia's [gothamjs presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/lukemelia/ember-dot-js-the-architecture-advantage)

> Are there any good resources to help me learn Ember faster than digging into the source?

Reading the source is always a good option, but there are many other resources. I recommend checking out [embercasts](http://www.embercasts.com) and [ember weekly](http://emberweekly.com/issues.html)

Comment: Ok, that clears it a lot. (Big thanks for the links you provided too). If I am not using ember-data, how am I to implement such a cache? I mean where are all the records fetched from the server "stored" in Ember? Where would such a cache live in order to be available from many controllers?

Comment: There is not one _right_ way to implement such a cache. It could be a simple array attached to a controller like `App.WeatherController` or a custom object like `App.WeatherStore`. If its a custom object you would probably use an initializer to set it up and inject into controllers, checkout http://nerdyworm.com/blog/2013/04/03/ember-initializers for example. Beyond that you might look at ember-data itself & follow the same pattern or consider an alternative like [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) or [EPF](http://epf.io). In all cases cache is just an in-memory array.